# extract and show album art of mp3 file in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a small mp3 player on android. So far so good, but I cant implement the following feature:

When playback of the file starts, check the file, get the artwork and display it.
(the artwork is embedded)

I've seen several libraries which claim to be capable of doing so, but I did not manage to implement it. (jaudiotagger, jid3)

Did somebody ever implement this and can show me some code?

Thank, Nico

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't support the standard ImageIO libraries which is why this part of jaudiotagger doesnt work with Android, there is an outstanding issue on jaudiotagger to resolve this issue for android.

Comment: i've seen that if you use ContentProvider there might be a chance to access the artwork. I'll give that a try.